# Python overwrite a dictionary sequentially at certain size

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

I have a script that constantly adds data to a dictionary(cannot be changed meaning no lists or to stop adding the data). It can easily reach over 1000 different keys within it.

I require each key and value but don't want to reset the dictionary `foo`.

```py
foo = {"369610": "a", "109122": "a", "907897": "a", "333291":"a", "381819": "a", "387583": "a", "677430": "a", "660221": "a", "118095":"a", "612172": "a"}

print(len(foo))  # At 10

foo["223533"] = "a"  # Replaces 369610 in the dictionary
foo["601336"] = "a"  # Replaces 109122 in the dictionary

print(len(foo))  # Should be 10
```

If I was to add more keys to the dictionary, it would replace 907897 then 333291 then 381819 and then 387583. Once it reaches the limit of 10 any more added would replace the first index 223533. I still want to access each value of each key as to why this is a dictionary and not a list.

I have thought to iterate over the dictionary then get each entry and overwrite that one with:

```py
del foo[index]
foo[random.randint(5000,100000)] = "a"
```

But I feel like this is an inefficient solution.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is, do you want a fixed-sized dictionary? Like `collections.deque` but for a dict?

Comment: I am honestly stumped just by your first code sample with comments. What is that supposed to mean? `foo["223533"] = "a"  # Replaces 369610`. Please add more information for mere mortals like myself.

Comment: Bro, you're a steward. I don't understand how can you think this question is formatted well and understandable to anyone else except for you.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan, the OP wants a `LifoQueue`, `"369610": "a"` go out when `foo["223533"] = "a"` come in

Comment: @Corralien Ah, I get it now! I have no idea why would he want a `dict` in that case, but ok. Also, you probably meant `FiFo`, right?

Comment: Yes... FIFO, sorry. Maybe, his program has grown and he has to have a dictionary but he wants to limit the number of entries. I can understand that.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan dict is so I can access each value by its key, I would of gone for a list if I didn't need to

Comment: @FluxedScript This line, `foo[random.randint(5000,100000)] = "a"` - that's purely for show, right? You don't actually randomly generate those keys, right?

Comment: Yes @CaptainTrojan I have no control over what the key will be but it is an integer

Comment: @FluxedScript Do you require deletion of key-value pairs, or do you need only to insert a pair and look pairs up?

Comment: An idea: you can subclass `OrderedDict` and override `__setitem__` with a `deque` encapsulation.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Yes I will have to remove the pair by key same as what a dict would do (insert,update,delete)

Comment: @FluxedScript I was afraid of that, that complicates things a bit. A fixed-size rotating ordered collection is very nicely implemented using an array, but it does not support deletion of arbitrary elements.

Comment: The ordering should be implemented using a linked list. You're probably looking for an equivalent of java's `LinkedHashMap`, only with a fixed size, which is easy to implement (remove the linked-list's head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class FooDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=5, /, *args, **kwds):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if len(self) > self.maxsize:
            oldest = next(iter(self))
            del self[oldest]
```

```
foo = FooDict()

for i in range(10):
    foo[random.randint(5000,100000)] = "a"
    print(foo)

FooDict([(82596, 'a')])
FooDict([(82596, 'a'), (67860, 'a')])
FooDict([(82596, 'a'), (67860, 'a'), (13232, 'a')])
FooDict([(82596, 'a'), (67860, 'a'), (13232, 'a'), (45835, 'a')])
FooDict([(82596, 'a'), (67860, 'a'), (13232, 'a'), (45835, 'a'), (15591, 'a')])
FooDict([(67860, 'a'), (13232, 'a'), (45835, 'a'), (15591, 'a'), (36689, 'a')])
FooDict([(13232, 'a'), (45835, 'a'), (15591, 'a'), (36689, 'a'), (60175, 'a')])
FooDict([(45835, 'a'), (15591, 'a'), (36689, 'a'), (60175, 'a'), (87882, 'a')])
FooDict([(15591, 'a'), (36689, 'a'), (60175, 'a'), (87882, 'a'), (59414, 'a')])
FooDict([(36689, 'a'), (60175, 'a'), (87882, 'a'), (59414, 'a'), (87218, 'a')])
```

Comment: Wow, what does the slash in `__init__` do?

Comment: By the way, I like your solution, +1. However, I heard somewhere that `for a in l: break` is faster than `a = next(iter(l))`. Is that incorrect? Have you tried this? Or do you just prefer more readable code?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know for `/`. It's just the signature of [`__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91db097358bcb00832e53d410035a8b7fcfdd9c3/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L110)

Comment: I'm not really aware about performance except for Pandas, I prefer a readable code.

Comment: @Corralien, the `/` means that the arguments *before* it are positional-only, there's also `*` (shown [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91db097358bcb00832e53d410035a8b7fcfdd9c3/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L116)), which means that the arguments *after* it are keyword-only

Answer (score 1):

Well, if anyone comes here looking for a dictionary which does not allow rewriting of keys nor their deletion (only insertion and lookup), then this is my solution:

```
class CircularBuffer:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.maxsize = size

        self.array = [None] * size
        self.ptr = 0
        self.get_ordered = self.GOpartial
        self.add = self.ADDpartial
        self.len = self.LENpartial

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.array[item]

    def LENpartial(self):
        return self.ptr

    def LENfull(self):
        return self.maxsize

    def ADDpartial(self, item):
        self.array[self.ptr] = item
        self.ptr = self.ptr + 1
        if self.ptr == self.maxsize:
            self.add = self.ADDfull
            self.get_ordered = self.GOfull
            self.len = self.LENfull
            self.ptr = 0
        return None

    def ADDfull(self, item):
        ret = self.array[self.ptr]
        self.array[self.ptr] = item
        self.ptr = (self.ptr + 1) % self.maxsize
        return ret

    def GOpartial(self):
        return self.array[:self.ptr]

    def GOfull(self):
        return self.array[self.ptr:] + self.array[0: self.ptr]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.array.__repr__()

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len()



class CircularBufferDict:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.keys = CircularBuffer(size)
        self.mapping = {}
        
    def add(self, k, v):
        if k in self.mapping:
            raise KeyError(f"Key {k} already exists in the dictionary.")
            
        rewritten = self.keys.add(k)
        if rewritten is not None:
            del self.mapping[rewritten]
        self.mapping[k] = v
        
    def get(self, k):
        return self.mapping[k]
```

After the maximum size is reached, it keeps a constant amount of elements. Every operation time belongs to `O(1)` (amortized on hash lookup). Deletion (and therefore overwriting) is inefficient when using this structure (defragmenting the array would take linear time).